# Adding rows to a table

Tags: xcode, tableview

I have a table with objects added with NSArray called listOfConjProcedures I want to use an insert control that appears above the top row in the table to add rows to my table when tapping the edit button in a UInavigation controller and I cannot find a good sample code.
The edit function looks like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([tableView isEditing])
        return [listOfConjProcedures count] + 1;
    else
        return [listOfConjProcedures count];    
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [listOfConjProcedures removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.

          }            
        }
```

I don't know how to proceed with the insert function to introduce a new row when the edit button is tapped (At the bottom of the posted code).
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This links helps you for insert new row [link1](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-DeleteandaddrowfromTableView.html) [link2](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/29/iphone-sdk-tutorial-add-delete-reorder-uitableview-row/) [link3](http://knol.google.com/k/iphone-sdk-using-table-views#)